Autocomplete WooCommerce orders doesn't work if stock level is 0 after order
Here's what I would like to achieve:
If someone places an order on the website and all items in the cart are in stock in the quantity ordered, the order status should automatically change from "Processing" to "Completed".
The code works fine, but if there is no stock left of a product after the order is placed (the stock is 0 of the product after the order is placed), the function will not work, example:

I ordered 10 example products, the stock level is 11. The code works fine.
I ordered 11 example products, the stock level is 11. The code doesn't work.

Here is my current code:
// Autocomplete orders
add_action('woocommerce_order_status_processing','check_stock_and_update_order_status',10,2);

function check_stock_and_update_order_status($order_id, $order) {
    // Get all items in the order
    $items = $order->get_items();
    $all_in_stock = true;

    // Check stock level for each product
    foreach ($items as $item_id => $item) {
        $product = $item->get_product();
        $product_stock = $product->get_stock_quantity();

        // If stock is insufficient, set flag to false
        if ($product_stock < $item->get_quantity()) {
            $all_in_stock = false;
            break;
        }
    }

    // Update order status based on stock availability
    if ($all_in_stock) {
        $order->update_status('completed');
    }
}


Did you tried if ($product_stock <= $item->get_quantity()) { instead?
